# Using R package broom causes error in ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, broom

I used R package `broom` for getting my results as data.frame from `lm()`.
This worked well, but causes problem with my `ifelse` command.
Script that worked well before installing the broom package is following:

```
df$newvariable <- ifelse((df$oldvariable == 0) | is.na(df$oldvariable), 0,
                                  ifelse((df$oldvariable == 1), 1, df$newvariable))
```

Now it gives following error:

> Error in ifelse((df$oldvariable == 1), 1, df$newvariable) :
>   replacement has length zero In addition: Warning messages: 1: Unknown
>   column 'newvariable'  2: In rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :   'x'
>   is NULL so the result will be NULL

I can avoid this still, if i don't install `broom` package. No changes to original data.frame has been made that could cause this.

Why `broom` package causes `ifelse` command to fail?

Comment: installation of a package won't cause ifelse to fail as per my exp. Please check the data

Comment: There error message is the clue here. It looks like `df` doesn't have the column `newvariable` when you access it.